How significant is the parabolic arch effected with an incline versus a decline in angle versus a decline in angle . For example throwing a dart
A dart players height can vary as can the height in which they raise their arm to aim.
Is there less parabolic arch when throwing at the same strength from above the target compared to below, due to gravity and to what extent?
From a physics perspective which method due to the physics maths perspective provides a truer flight path?

there is no physics definition of "truer" flight path, so the question us unanswerable. Why don't you write down the eqs. of motion for a level (end-to-end) trajectory, get the Jacobian, and compute how much phase space hits the bullseye for different initial conditions? Sounds like a fun problem.
